# Доступ к элементу массива

Tags: delphi

Как изменить (получить доступ к элементу) элемент массива через указатель на него?

```
var
  q: array of integer;
  Pq: pointer;
begin
pq:=addr(q);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, наверное, так. Может быть, есть способ лучше, но мне подобное приходилось делать пару раз. В Си и Си++ с указателями на массивы (и на элементы) всё намного проще и интереснее. На мой взгляд, лучше не использовать указатели, если можно обойтись без них.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

Var
  Mas: Array[0..99] Of Integer;
  PMas: ^Integer;
  i, n: Byte;

begin
  Write(' n = ');
  ReadLn(n);

  Randomize;
  For i:=0 To N-1 Do
    Begin
      // PMas:=Addr(Mas[i]); можно написать так
      PMas:=@Mas[i];
      PMas^:=Random(100)-Random(100);
      WriteLn(' ', PMas^);
    End;

  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: Для демонстрации достаточно было Random(100). Если нужны были числа от -100 до 100, можно было сделать Random(200)-100, а Random(100)-Random(100) дает неравномерное распределение.

Comment: Да какая разница, главное пример показать. Я просто так уже привык писать, а над этой математикой я не задумывался.

Comment: Для демонстрации можно было бы например записать в по адресу PMas какое-нибудь определенное число, а потом показать что в Mas[i] находится именно оно) Но да, это все мелочи
P.S. в любом случае было интересно узнать как это делается в Delphi